# Is it possible to block shares on a Terminal Server Session?

Tags: network-share, rdp, terminal-server, windows-firewall

So i have the following issue. I want to have a very restricted Terminal Server in a domain where a user can log on using RDP and only view certain files (on local TS drive). Its very important that the user is not possible to steal or move this files in any way.

I allready removed the clipboard beteween the local pc and the TS as well as the connection of local devices like USB/Printer or local drives. The internet access is blocked as well. So the only thing thats left for me is to restrain the TS session to access shares in the network. I tried to block the ports 445, 135,137 and 139 to accomplish my goal but as soon as i do this im not able to access the RDP ression anymore.

So my question is, how do i block the access to the shares or network without blocking the RDP ression itself? There has to be a way ;)!!

btw. I know that i could just create a new domain user only for the purpose to connect to the TS and do not give this user any rights on shares or the domain but but i dont want to have multiple user account for a single user. So the user have  to access the TS session with his normal user he uses to access his local workstation.

Comment: i don't get it, where do the user get his permissions in the first place?

Comment: Its a simple domain with a file server, dc and TS. Users have domain accounts and of cause the domain accounts having permissions to access e.g shares on the file server, but i dont want the users to access the file server shares when they are using the TS session because that would allow them to copy the files to the fileserver and then to thier local pc "to steal the file".

Comment: Assuming the only shares you have are all in one place (on the file server) you could block traffic to it's IP.

Comment: Tought that as well but the Server is the 2nd DC with the role DC and Fileserver and of cause i want to prevent blocking DNS or AD services from the DC.